# Creating spans that hide when another object is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my html:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <table id="table1">
        <tr>
            <th>Table</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a rel="img1">Link1</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a rel="img2">Link2</a>
            </td>            
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="box">
    <img src="cant-believe-it-icon.png" id="img1"/>
    <img src="too-much-icon.png" id="img2"/>
</div>

<span>Text with fist image</span>
<span>Text with second image</span>
```

And my jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    imgid = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    $('img').hide();    
    $('#'+imgid).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

When the first td is clicked, the first image is visible. When the second td is clicked, the first image is hidden, and the second image is visible. How do I apply this to the spans as well?

Update: I set for all images and spans a class="groups". Then I paired the first image with the first span etc. using id="group1", "group2" and so on. Then I set the rel's of the td's to "group1", "group2" etc. The javascript now reads:

```
$( window ).load(function() {
    $(".groups").hide()
    $('a').click(function(){
    var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(".groups").hide()
    $('#'+rel).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Everything hides when opened, but when the td's are clicked nothing happens?

Answer (score 2):

### [Solution](http://jsbin.com/jasux/1/)

#### HTML

```
<div id="box">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/&text=img1" class="img1"/>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250/&text=img2" class="img2"/>
</div>

<span class="img1">Text with fist image</span>
<span class="img2">Text with second image</span>
```

#### CSS

```
$('a').click(function(){
  var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
  $('a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('img').hide();    
  $('span').hide();   
  $('.'+rel).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: Can I suggest adding the hides outside of the click function so they don't show by default?  http://jsbin.com/kamayuju/1/

Also, why not just put the `<img>` inside the span?

Comment: did you changed the html?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ID in the image, use a particular class and add the same class to the spans also. So when alongwith the image with that class, spans will also be shown/hidden. Modified Code:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    imgid = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('img,span').hide();    
    $('.'+imgid).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Here is the link for jsfiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/EuGr3/

Comment: In your example, what do I need to change in the javascript to set to my image classes? For example, if I set the first image and span's class to "group1" and the second set to "group2", what should the javascript read? (I haven't got round to learning javascript yet).

Comment: Let's say that you have to hide "group2" class, then in replace this code: "$('img,span').hide();" with $('.group2').hide(); .

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function(){

    imgid = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    $('img').hide();    
    $('span').hide();
    spanid = imgid.substr(4) - 1*1;
    $('#'+imgid).fadeIn('slow');
    $('span:eq('+spanid+')').fadeIn('slow');

});
```

Comment: `imgid.substr(4) - 1*1`... why?

Answer (score 0):

It works as the same..

Look jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kychan/j8vqX/

```
$('a.show').click(function()
{
    $('.hideSpan').fadeIn();
});

$('a.hide').click(function()
{
    $('.hideSpan').fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your `rel` attribute on the spans:

```
<span rel="img1">Text with fist image</span>
<spa rel="img2">Text with second image</span>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    imgid = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('a, span').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    $('img, span').hide();    
    $('#'+imgid + ', span[rel="' + imgid + '"]').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Sidenote: it would be better to use a `data-rel` attribute, as that's what the `data-*` attributes are for.